# Excel VBA to Delete Rows with Zeros, Wrong Operator?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clean-up my spreadsheet by removing any rows for which column C  contains zero.

The code runs but the zeros remain. Should I be using `Is Nothing`?

How would I define it?

```
    Sub CleanUp()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Oppo As Long
Dim CheckLoop As Long
Dim RowCount As Long ' <-- define RowCount as Long
Dim DelRng As Range

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

With sh
    RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "C"

    For CheckLoop = RowCount To 2 Step -1
        If .Range("C" & CheckLoop).Value = 0 Then ' <== modified this line
            If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Rows(CheckLoop))
            Else
                Set DelRng = .Rows(CheckLoop)
            End If
        End If
    Next CheckLoop
End With
' if range object is not empty >> delete entire rows at 1-line
If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.Delete

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Comment: Make sure you declare it as a long before setting it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting line-by-line, you can add a `DelRng` object, use `Union` to merge all rows which answer your criteria, and at the end just delete them all at once using `DelRng.Delete`.

More explanation why you got your error in the code below, as comments.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CleanUp()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Oppo As Long
Dim CheckLoop As Long
Dim RowCount As Long ' <-- define RowCount as Long
Dim DelRng As Range

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

With sh
    RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "A"

    For CheckLoop = RowCount To 2 Step -1
        If .Range("C" & CheckLoop).Value = 0 Then ' <== modified this line
            If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Rows(CheckLoop))
            Else
                Set DelRng = .Rows(CheckLoop)
            End If
        End If
    Next TotalLoop
End With
' if range object is not empty >> delete entire rows at 1-line
If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Won't this throw an error at `Oppo = .Cells(TotalLoop, 3)`? Shouldn't it be `Oppo = .Cells(TotalLoop, 3).Value` or does Excel automatically knows you want the Value since you declared `Oppo`as `Long`?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost you are right, it's better practice to use it, even though Excel's default is `Value`. It might throw an error anyway, as I am not sure how and where `TotalLoop` is calculated, since OP didn't mention it

Comment: @ShaiRado The code is not deleting the cells with a zero value like I thought it would. It just runs. TotalLoop is CheckLoop. It was a typo when asking the question, sorry.

Comment: @Remi try edited code, I wrote in the comments the line I modifed

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you for your help Shai! Works perfectly.

Comment: @ShaiRado Can VBA find `#REF!` as well?  So I change the line to this `If Not DelRng Is Nothing Or "#REF!" Then` ?

Comment: @Remi yes, but it's an entire different code. You should post another question, and describe what else you want to check

Comment: @ShaiRado Fair enough. On this code, for some reason, I am getting a type mismatch error here `Oppo = .Cells(CheckLoop, 3)`. So it only ran properly once. Any idea why?

Comment: @Remi where ? check my code above, I don't have this line

Comment: @ShaiRado Sorry, even with your code, it gives the error. I corrected your code to remove the `TotalLoop`. Changed it to `CheckLoop` since I figured you meant that. See above.